# Why is dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1 started so frequently?

Tags: systemd, ntp, dbus, systemd-timesyncd

I have some Ubuntu 18.04.1 servers. They all show this service being started rougly every 10 minutes.

```
Jan  7 06:29:05 csrf-prod1-vm dbus-daemon[434]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.service' requested by ':1.12841' (uid=0 pid=25418 comm="timedatectl " label="unconfined")
Jan  7 06:29:05 csrf-prod1-vm systemd[1]: Starting Time & Date Service...
Jan  7 06:29:05 csrf-prod1-vm dbus-daemon[434]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
Jan  7 06:29:05 csrf-prod1-vm systemd[1]: Started Time & Date Service.
```

Perhaps of note is I have configured `timesyncd` with some network-local ntp servers.

```
$ timedatectl status
                      Local time: Mon 2019-01-07 18:15:54 UTC
                  Universal time: Mon 2019-01-07 18:15:54 UTC
                        RTC time: Mon 2019-01-07 18:15:55
                       Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

It appears that this service just starts `systemd-timedated`. Is this what's used by `systemd-timesyncd` in order to set the time? Why does it not stay running as the suffix d[aemon] would suggest? Or is it redundant to `systemd-timesyncd` and should be disabled in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that a configuration management system was calling `timedatectl` every ~10 minutes in order to check the current timezone.

This calls `timedate1` over DBUS to get the answer, which only activates on incoming messages.

So entirely normal, and entirely my fault.

Comment: you can accept this as the correct answer!

Comment: @Anon I know. I wasn't very happy with myself.

Answer (score 2):

`systemd-timesyncd` is one-shot so it's more of an SNTP client rather than an NTP one. I've seen situations where it was triggered each time you get a DHCP lease and if your leases have a short period it is triggered frequently. The snippet of the log you enclosed doesn't give enough information though - that just looks like one activation and start...

Comment: That's all the logs I can see (in syslog). Just that repeated every 10 min.

Comment: @OrangeDog How long does your DHCP last for and how frequently is it renewed?

Comment: `netplan` shows a lease lifetime of 43200. The logs for `systemd-networkd` show a DHCP event every few days. So it's probably not that.

Comment: Also, neither `systemd-timesyncd` nor `systemd-timedated` are one-shot. They are notify and simple, respectively.

Comment: Fair enough. You might be able to find out who is doing the regular dbus activation (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379997/109111 ) assuming that's what you're seeing every 10 minutes.

Comment: Doesn't the log already show what's activating dbus - `uid=0 pid=25418 comm="timedatectl "`? Problem is I don't know what's calling that.